# MFC: After applying a CSplitterWnd to my CChildFrame the main window title isn't updated any more

Tags: mfc, csplitterwnd

Still using VS 2008, I have split my MDI view class in my `CChildFrame` to facilitate a navigation sidebar (a `CListCtrl`) next to my old `CScrollView` using a static splitter ([source code](https://github.com/Thomas-Mielke-Software/EasyCash/blob/2c0c5eb375771362a01ce5b0433606f903e34942/childfrm.cpp#L91-L121)). This however implied two side effects: Beside the mouse wheel no longer working ([where I found a workaround for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66157858/1284927)), the application window is no longer updated on `SetPathName()`. What do I need to do to bridge the splitter so the framework updates the application window again based on my `CDocument`?

Comment: Where do you call SetPahName()? And style FWS_ADDTOTITLE must be set.

Comment: FWS_ADDTOTITLE is set in the frame. Before I applied the splitter, it worked, as FWS_ADDTOTITLE is default in a MDI app. I tried to call CSplitterWnd::CreateStatic() with it, but it didn't change anything. SetPahName() is being called in my CDocument class, e.g. in OnNewDocument() or in OnFileSaveAs().

Comment: On your MainFrame class, just put a method 
`void CMyFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle(BOOL bAddToTitle)
{
 __super::OnUpdateFrameTitle(bAddToTitle);
}`
and a breakpoint there, to see what happens. If needed, you will have to provide your own override instead of calling the `__super` implementation.

Comment: After a lengthy bisect search, I got the window titles back to normal after commenting out the `FWS_ADDTOTITLE` style, I must have added in `PreCreateWindow()` after TomTom's comment. I can't recover all the other changes I made. One of them must have solved the document title problem...

Answer (score 1):

On your MainFrame class, just put a method

```
void CMyFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle(BOOL bAddToTitle)
{
    __super::OnUpdateFrameTitle(bAddToTitle);
}
```

and a breakpoint there, to see what happens. If needed, you will have to provide your own override instead of calling the `__super` implementation.

Comment: When querying `GetActiveDocument()` in `CMDIFrameWnd::OnUpdateFrameTitle` it always return NULL. So replacing my `CScrollView` with a `CSplitterWnd` with two `CView`-derived classes somehow broke the connection of the document and the framework. This was due to `CFrameWnd::GetActiveView()` never revealed an active view. I also added a `SetActivePane()` and `SetActiveView()` in `CChildFrame::OnCreateClient` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: PS: `CMainFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle()` is being called several times, after adding the override. There is still just the application name displayed in the windows title without the document name.

Comment: Now you have to dig into the call stack to know more details.

Comment: I dug as far as I could. The question is: Where do I have to override what function to have the active document set, so that it can be found by the framework again, without having to read the complete MFC source code?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `CFrameWnd::GetActiveDocument` function : https://i.imgur.com/WaLX09m.png to see what is getting returned.

Comment: Gets a valid document via `CMDIFrameWnd::OnUpdateFrameTitle()` but I noticed it won't pass this check `if (pActiveChild != NULL && (pActiveChild->GetStyle() & WS_MAXIMIZE) == 0)` as the window style obviously doesn't indicate that the window is maximized. Ironically, if I normalize the MDI child windows, the application window gets the document name, but the child windows don't have a title. I also remember that after adding the splitter, the child window started normalized (maximised before) and I had to call `CMDIChildWndEx::ActivateFrame(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)` in `CChildFrame::ActivateFrame`.